# Ruby on Rails - render login page after session expire

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I would like to render login page after session expire in my rails application. I didn't use any gem for authentication. Any help would be appreciated please. The below is my application controller.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :session_expiry, :except => [:login]

  def current_user
    if session[:user_id].nil?
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
  helper_method :current_user 

  def session_expiry
    expire_time = session[:expires_at] || Time.now
    @time_left = (expire_time - Time.now).to_i
    unless @time_left > 0
      reset_session
      flash[:error] = 'Session Timeout!'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what does `reset_session` do? Does it redirect to the login page?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to define another method into application_controller.js to check if the session expire and redirect if this is the case:

```
def redirect_to_login_if_session_expire
  redirect_to(login_path) if session[:user_id].nil?
end
```

Where the `:user_id` could be the `current_user.id`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I edited my question as i changed. Could you please have a look. My problem now is i cannot redirect to login page.

Comment: Is reset_session another method inside application controller? Maybe inside this method could you call or change it for a redirect_to login_path

Comment: The problem is my login method already had redirect_to inside. If i again call like "redirect_to login_path" then I got error.